# Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format Gitlab CI

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml

This is piece of my yaml file about ssh for gitlab ci:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
'[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

When I attempted to set `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable to protected state, it occurs error:

> Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format

and I don't know why it's okay when I set `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable to unprotected state

Answer (score 12):

For me it also failed because the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` was marked as "Protected" but the tag I was using was not.

So either make the branch or tag you are using also protected or remove the "Protected" setting from the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable.

See: https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README#create-a-custom-variable-in-the-ui

> Protect variable (Optional): If selected, the variable will only be available in pipelines that run on protected branches or tags.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot.

Comment: This helped so much! I was using a protected branch, but as soon as I ran it on a tag, things stopped working. Apparently my tags weren't protected.

Answer (score 8):

this is because you set SSH_PRIVATE_KEY in a malformed state. my suggestion is to use base64 encoded value in the variable

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_ras | base64 -w0
```

add this value to your gitlab ci variable then in your gitlab.ci.yml

```
ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Settings > CI/CD > Variables

1. Make sure that your SSH_PRIVATE_KEY is file type.
2. Check if you are using TAGS, if not... check if the file is marked as Protected, uncheck.
3. If you copy paste from CAT, make sure that there is a blank line after your last line. Just press enter after:

-----END ... PRIVATE KEY-----

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I saved the key on GITLAB CI as file. changed it variable, problem sloved.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could also happen because you have created `4096` bit keys. For some reason this fails in pipeline.

Make sure to create `2048` ones or use `file` as variable type.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions here did not work for me, also see related question:

[How to add ssh private key from Gitlab CI variable with ssh-add?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73034008/how-to-add-ssh-private-key-from-gitlab-ci-variable-with-ssh-add)

=> I use a shell executor, and instead of copying the private key from a CI variable, I manually configured an ssh connection between the gitlab-runner host and the target server (needs to be done for the user "gitlab-runner").

Also see:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-shell-executor